# Remote Interpreter: Error:Couldn't read integer value from stream

Tags: pyspark, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I was finally able to connect to a Jupyter Notebook that is running on a remote machine in a PySpark context.

```
[my machine] <----> [hadoop-cluster](runs jupyter notebook in pyspark)
```

So what I can do now is run the code on my remote machine from withn PyCharm:

[image]

The (remote) interpreter config:

[image]

Here is the thing: I am able to execute cells, process data and can `plt.plot()` or `print()` stuff - but there's one issue:

If I **re-run** a cell e.g.

```
print(nb_total_documents)
```

the output is not displayed again. I have to re-run the cell 5 to 10 times, then the output will show up again.

---

**1. Showing up:**

[image]

---

**2. Re-running makes it disappear:**

[image]

---

**3. Re-running it multiple times makes it show up again:**

[image]

---

This can get a bit frustrating especially for code that runs longer.

The only error I can say which I assume might be related is

> Error:Couldn't read integer value from stream

in the Python Console.

Any idea what the problem might be here?

Comment: Which browser do you use? Does your browser window have a different scale?

Comment: @miindlek I am running this inside PyCharm - idk what they are using there.

Comment: Why do you want to connect pycharm with your jupyter-notebook? I would rather choose only one of them. So whats the benefit?

Comment: @miindlek Because the notebook runs on a remote machine - not locally.

Comment: Do you have the same issues, when connecting via terminal?

Comment: Ok, so why do you want to use pycharm at all? why don't you just connect via browser

Comment: @miindlek Via terminal? I don'tk now - I know I can do it by connecting using e.g. Chrome - then it's working as usual. The reason why I want to do this is convenience. My notebooks may be using code from within the project and I do not want to manage the local and the remote files. If I get this to work on my local machine I can do *everything* locally without having to think about version control on my remote machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170360/discussion-between-stefan-falk-and-miindlek).